# undeclared identifier when trying to use my own class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to Xcode & Objective C.  I am trying to create and use my own class.

```
//NSObject+Bridge.h
@interface NSObject (Bridge)
- (void)modify_coredata:(NSString *)table rows:(NSString *)rows;
@end

// NSObject+Bridge.m
#import "NSObject+Bridge.h"
@implementation NSObject (Bridge)
- (void)modify_coredata:(NSString *)table rows:(NSString *)rows {
    NSLog(@"table: %@", table);
    NSLog(@"rows : %@", rows);
}
```

In my `ViewController.m` file, I have `#import "NSObject+Bridge.h"` near the top of the file.

Inside the `viewDidLoad` method of `ViewController.m`, I tried both of these lines of code.  They both fail with this error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'Bridge'`.

```
Bridge *b1; = [[Bridge alloc] init];
Bridge *b2;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't declare a class named `Bridge`. All you have done is create a category on `NSObject` named `Bridge`. Two completely different and unrelated things.

A class named `Bridge` would be in files named `Bridge.h` and `Bridge.m` and be declared as:

```
@interface Bridge : NSObject
```

Perhaps you want:

Bridge.h

```
@interface Bridge : NSObject

- (void)modify_coredata:(NSString *)table rows:(NSString *)rows;

@end
```

Bridge.m

```
#import "Bridge.h"

@implementation Bridge

- (void)modify_coredata:(NSString *)table rows:(NSString *)rows {
    NSLog(@"table: %@", table);
    NSLog(@"rows : %@", rows);
}
```

BTW - typical naming conventions for methods mean your method should really be named:

```
modifyCoreData:rows:
```

Note the use of camel case instead of using underscores.

Comment: In Xcode, when I add a file, what to choose for file type? Empty, Category, Protocol, or Extension?

Comment: File, New..., File..., iOS, Source, Cocoa Touch Class, Next.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). So directly you can use `category` method to the existing class without initializing it.